# Покраска моделей в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Я экспортировал модель из 3DMAX в юнити. Как я могу покрасить эту модель в самом Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity не предназначена для того чтобы текстурировать модель, только если в AssetStore найдете что-нибудь из плагинов. А если вы просто хотите единым цветом модель залить, создаете материал, выбираете на нем шейдер и в шейдере как правило есть MainColor изменяя который вы меняете цвет материала.